# Cannot import Switch component from react-router-dom in WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webstorm

I am using React-Router in WebStorm. I cannot import Switch component from "react-router-dom"

[image: React]-

I deleted all node_modules and re-install npm. But it didn't solve the issue. react-router-dom version is 6.2.2

Comment: In react router v6 `Switch` is replaced with `Routes`. Check the docs: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Answer (score 1):

`<Switch>` was removed sine version 6 [see upgrade-to-react-router-v6](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/upgrading/v5.md#upgrade-to-react-router-v6)

> Upgrade all `<Switch>` elements to `<Routes>` React Router v6 introduces a Routes component that is kind of like Switch, but a lot more powerful. The main advantages of Routes over Switch are: All `<Route>`s and `<Link>`s inside a `<Routes>` are relative. This leads to leaner and more predictable code in `<Route path>` and `<Link to>`
> Routes are chosen based on the best match instead of being traversed in order. This avoids bugs due to unreachable routes because they were defined later in your `<Switch>`
> Routes may be nested in one place instead of being spread out in different components. In small to medium-sized apps, this lets you easily see all your routes at once. In large apps, you can still nest routes in bundles that you load dynamically via React.lazy

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
// ...

    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="users/*" element={<Users />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
```